# jquery tablesorter: sorting filter select field that is using extracted text

Tags: tablesorter

I'm using the JQuery tablesorter plugin and I"m trying to sort a filter select list (alphabetically).

The column has full names of people with their titles and I only want to sort by last name. In addition I want the select field to filter those names and display the full name alphabetically in the drop down.

So far, I have the data parsed by textExtraction and the sort works. I set filter_useParsedData to true, but it is only showing the extracted text (last name) in the select field.

```
$('table').tablesorter({

theme: 'blue',

textExtraction: {
  0: function(node, table, cellIndex){ return $(node).find("lname").text(); }},

widgets: ['columns', 'filter', 'stickyHeaders', 'zebra'],
widgetOptions : {
    filter_useParsedData : true, }
});
```

Here is a demo of the table http://jsfiddle.net/UwKge/.

Anyway this can work?

Comment: I made a small update to the code http://jsfiddle.net/UwKge/2/

Comment: Sorry for not responding earlier, but try out the new  [`filter_selectSource` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-selectsource), you won't need to rely on the textExtraction function and can sort or modify the data however you wish.